# Java Filter an array by another Boolean array of size n

Tags: java, arrays, list, boolean, filtering

I am new to Java. I have an array `Arr` of size n, this array `Arr` may contain, say, double. (This array may be of another type: e.g. integer, string or any other object: `double[]`, `int[]`, or `List<Object>`).

I have another Boolean array `BooArr` of size n, containing `true` or `false`.

What is the most concise code to filter the `Arr` based on the `BooArr`.
In matlab/python, it will be very easy as: `ValidArrElements = Arr[BooArr]`.
E.g. `Arr = [1, 2.0, -1, 3]`, `BooArr = [true, true, false, true]`, and `ValidArrElements` will be `[1, 2.0, 3]`.

What will be the concise code in Java (without using loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the restriction that in Java, `arr` can contain only a single type...

```java
IntStream.range(0, n).filter(i -> booArr[i])
        .mapToObj(n -> arr[n]).[some terminal operation]
```

Start with a sequence of all the array indexes, select only the ones mapped to `true` in `booArr`, then select those indexes from `arr` and apply the terminal operation of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter these two arrays using `IntStream`:

```java
// assume that two arrays have the same
// length, or 'booArr' is less than 'arr'
Object[] arr = new Object[]{1, 2.0, -1, 3};
Boolean[] booArr = {true, true, false, true};

Object[] validArr = IntStream
        // iterate through array indexes
        .range(0, booArr.length)
        // filter trues
        .filter(i -> booArr[i])
        // take values that are true
        .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
        // return an array
        .toArray();

// output
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(validArr));
// [1, 2.0, 3]
```

If you have two lists, the approach is the same:

```java
// assume that two lists have the same
// length, or 'booList' is less than 'list'
List<Object> list = List.of(1, 2.0, -1, 3);
List<Boolean> booList = List.of(true, true, false, true);

List<Object> validList = IntStream
        // iterate through list indexes
        .range(0, booList.size())
        // filter trues
        .filter(booList::get)
        // take values that are true
        .mapToObj(list::get)
        // return a List<Object>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// output
System.out.println(validList);
// [1, 2.0, 3]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to sort a character by number of occurrences in a String using a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66535925/15309136)</sup>