# Trying to write code that calculates the average length of words in a sentence

Tags: java, string, methods, count

The code needs to have a method `averageLength` with the parameter `String s`. The method needs to return, as a `double` value, the average length of the words in `s`. Assuming `s` consists of only words separated by single blanks, without any leading or trailing blanks. I have a code below that finds the average length of words but it doesn't have the method `averageLength`:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please type in your sentence, then press enter: ");

        String words = sc.nextLine();

        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        sc = new Scanner(words);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            String userInput = sc.next();

            double charNum = userInput.length();
            sum = charNum + sum;
            count++;

            if (count > 0) {
                average = sum / count;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Average word length = " + average);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a method that returns a double and accepts a parameter of String

```
  private static double returnAverageLength(String sentence){
```

With the help of the `split()` method, we split the sentence into words

```
  String [] words = sentence.split(" ");
```

With a for loop we count all characters of the sentence

```
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            countCharacters+= words[i].length();
        }
```

And we return the average result

```
return countCharacters / words.length;
```

Full code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Write sentence");
       String s = scanner.nextLine();

       double average = returnAverageLength(s);

        System.out.println("AVERAGE IS " + average);

    }

    private static double returnAverageLength(String sentence){

        String [] words = sentence.split(" ");

        double countCharacters = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            countCharacters+= words[i].length();
        }



        return countCharacters / words.length;
    }

    
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Write sentence
Hello From Stackoverflow
AVERAGE IS 7.33
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 8* you can use [`DoubleStream#average`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average--) method for this purpose:

```java
public static double averageLength(String words) {
    return Arrays
            // split a string into an array of
            // words by spaces, returns Stream<String>
            .stream(words.split(" "))
            // take a word's length, returns DoubleStream
            .mapToDouble(String::length)
            // returns OptionalDouble
            .average()
            // if a value is not present, returns 0.0
            .orElse(0.0D);
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words = "Not all questions benefit from including code " +
            "but if your problem is with code you've written you " +
            "should include some But don't just copy in your entire " +
            "program Not only is this likely to get you in trouble " +
            "if you're posting your employer's code it likely includes " +
            "a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to " +
            "ignore when trying to reproduce the problem";

    System.out.println(averageLength(words)); // 4.671875
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Sort semantic versions in a given array as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66444911/15309136)</sup>