# How to sum the elements of the array up to the target number?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I am just trying to look through an array and find the elements that sum up to the target number. I've gotten this far into the program:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] numbers = {3, 6, 2, 9};
        int targNum = 5;

        twoSum(numbers, targNum);
    }

    public static void twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int sum = 0;

            if (nums[i] <= target) {
                int[] sumNums = {target - nums[i]};

                for (int j = 0; j < sumNums.length; j++) {
                    sum += sumNums[j];
                    System.out.println(sum);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting console output of:

```
2
3
```

I ran a simple array sum in another file and it seemed to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Set` to look through the given array only once.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] numbers = { 3, 6, 2, 9 };
        int targNum = 5;

        twoSum(numbers, targNum);
    }

    public static void twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();

        for (int a : nums) {
            int b = target - a;

            if (unique.contains(b)) {
                System.out.println(a + " " + b);
                return;
            }

            unique.add(a);
        }

        System.err.println("not found");

    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Didn't think about using a set to avoid duplicates, which was the next problem I was going to run into. Thanks!

Comment: @jpenn2472 You should accept the answer if helps resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) instead of `for-loop`:

```java
int[] numbers = {3, 6, 2, 9};
int targetSum = 5;
```

```java
// Map.Entry<Set<Integer>,Integer>
var entry = IntStream
        // iterating through the array indexes
        .range(0, numbers.length)
        // map each index as a pair of index and value,
        // i.e. set of indexes and sum of values
        // Stream<Map.Entry<Set<Integer>,Integer>>
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(Set.of(i), numbers[i]))
        // reduce stream of map entries to a single entry
        .reduce((e1, e2) -> {
            int sum = e1.getValue() + e2.getValue();
            // if sum of the values of the two entries
            // is less than or equal to the target sum
            if (sum <= targetSum) {
                // summarize two entries
                Set<Integer> key = new HashSet<>();
                key.addAll(e1.getKey());
                key.addAll(e2.getKey());
                return Map.entry(key, sum);
            } else {
                // otherwise, take an entry with a smaller sum
                return e1.getValue() < e2.getValue() ? e1 : e2;
            }
        }).orElse(null);
```

```java
// output
if (entry == null)
    System.out.println("Not found");
else
    entry.getKey().forEach(i -> System.out.println(numbers[i]));
```

Output:

```
3
2
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to sort a character by number of occurrences in a String using a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66535925/15309136)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

    int[] sum = new int[2];

    for(int i=0; i<nums.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                sum[0] = i;
                sum[1]= j;
                return sum;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
    
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] nums ={8,5,8,8,5,1 };
    int target = 9;
    Solution solution = new Solution(); 
    int[] sum = solution.twoSum(nums, target);
    if (sum != null) {
        System.out.println(sum[0] + " " + sum[1]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No two sum solution");
    }
    
}
```

}

nums ={8,5,8,8,5,1 };
Target = 9;

Comment: It would be easier to understand the code if you provided a little explanation attached with this solution code. By doing so, it would be a better help for different developers who have the same problem to the question poster.