# How to connect edges in a graph with n common properties?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to create a NFT graph in which each nft is a node and two nfts will have an edge between them if they have *at least* **n** owners in common.


For example:
nft1 has owners ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
nft2 has owners ['g', 'h', 'e', 's', 'a', 'b', 'd']
nft3 has owners ['g', 'h', 's', 'c']
and here n=3.
So now:

nft1 and nft2 are connected because they have 4 owners in common (['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])
nft2 and nft3 are connected because they have 3 owners in common (['g', 'h', 's'])
**BUT** nft1 and nft3 are ***not*** connected because they only have 1 owner in common (['c'])
[Result of the describes graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTH9D.png)

Does anyone have any idea how i can accomplish this?

Comment: There are many Q&A on this site about getting the intersection of two sets. You need the size of that intersection. So maybe search around depending on your language environment.

Comment: Thank you for answering :) can you lead me to one of these Q&As? I couldn't find one. The language doesn't matter, python would work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intersection+of+sets

Answer (score 0):

```
SORT nfts into order of decreasing number of owners
LOOP A over sorted nfts
   LOOP B over sorted nfts starting at A+1
      Count common owners of A and B
      IF count > N
          Add edge between A and B
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind https://stackoverflow.com/a/26028865/585411 applies here.

1. For each NFT emit `(owner, NFT)` pairs.
2. MapReduce groups by owner.
3. For each `(owner, [NFT1, NFT2, ...])` emit `((NFTi, NFTj), owner)` pairs with `i < j`.
4. MapReduce groups by NFT pairs.
5. For each `((NFTi, NFTj), [owner1, owner2, ...])` pair with enough owners, emit `(NFTi, NFTj)` and `(NFTj, NFTi)` pairs.
6. MapReduce groups by NFT
7. Each NFT now has a list of its edges.

This can be done in a distributed way with a real MapReduce. Or with a fake MapReduce as described there.  Or with a hashmap if you have relatively few owners and NFTs.  But the logic pattern remains the same.